# pandas - append on the first column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to add 2 additionals columns to `campaign-device.csv` (`custom_conversion_id` and `custom_conversion_name`) using pandas but seems there is no option to append those 2 columns to the beginning of the `.csv`. Any tips?

```
with open('output/campaign-device.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile,fieldnames=items[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(items)

csv_input = pandas.read_csv('output/campaign-device.csv')
csv_input['custom_conversion_id'] = '11197251455862'
csv_input['custom_conversion_name'] = 'total-device'
csv_input.to_csv('output/campaign-device.csv', index=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not append columns to the beginning, but you can rearrange columns order after adding your columns

```
 with open('output/campaign-device.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
     w = csv.DictWriter(outfile,fieldnames=items[0].keys())
     w.writeheader()
     w.writerows(items)
    
 csv_input = pandas.read_csv('output/campaign-device.csv')
    
 cols = [x for x in csv_input.columns]
 # or cols = csv_input.columns.tolist()
    
 csv_input['custom_conversion_id'] = '11197251455862'
 csv_input['custom_conversion_name'] = 'total-device'
    
 csv_input = csv_input[['custom_conversion_id', 'custom_conversion_name', *cols]]
    
 csv_input.to_csv('output/campaign-device.csv', index=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with the insert-Command from Pandas [Dok-link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([7, 8, 9]), columns=['c'])
print(df)
#DataFrame.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=False) 
df.insert(0, 'a', np.array([1, 2, 3]))
df.insert(1, 'b', np.array([4, 5, 6]))
print(df)
```